# Turning a set of parent-child relationships into a hierarchical structure

Tags: perl

I have an LDAP directory that I'm querying using [`Net::LDAP`](http://metacpan.org/module/Net::LDAP). This gives me a set of parent-child relationships.

It's a directory of people - and includes a 'manager' DN (which is another field within the directory).

I'm having real trouble turning this manager->person set of records into a hierarchical structure.

What I've got so far is:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Net::LDAP;
use Data::Dumper;

my %people;

my $ldap   = Net::LDAP->new('my_ldap_server');
my $result = $ldap->bind('bind_dn');
die if $result->code;

my $search = $ldap->search(
    base   => 'ou=yaddayadda',
    scope  => 'subtree',
    filter => 'objectClass=person',
    attrs  => ['manager'],
);
foreach my $found ( $search->entries ) {
    my $mgr = $found->get_value('manager');
    my $dn  = $result->dn;
    push( @{ $people{$mgr} }, $dn );
}
```

What this gives me is a hash of managers and the people who work for them (using DN, which is unique).

An entry from `%people` looks like:

```
$VAR1 = { 
            'cn=Firstname Lastname,ou=OrgUnit' => [
                          'cn=Personame Lastname,ou=OrgUnit',
                          'cn=AnotherPerson NameHere,ou=OrgUnit', 
                         ],
            'cn=AnotherPerson NameHere,ou=OrgUnit' => [
                         'cn=Someone Else,ou=OrgUnit', 
                         ]
           };
```

But I'm having trouble with turning that parent-child mapping into a hierarchical structure.

e.g.:

```
'ceo' => [
             'pa' => [],
             'head_of_dept' => [ 
                       'person' => [],
                       'person_with_staff' => [ 'person3', 'person4' ]
                    ]
          ]
```

I'm at something of a loss for how to accomplish this. It seems it shouldn't be too hard to do, given that each person is unique within the organisation structure.

NB - in the above, I've got `cn=AnotherPerson NameHere,ou=OrgUnit` who has a subordinate, and I'm after making a nested mapping out of this:

e.g.:

```
$VAR1 = {
          'cn=Firstname Lastname,ou=OrgUnit' => [
                                                  'cn=Personame Lastname,ou=OrgUnit',
                                                  'cn=AnotherPerson NameHere,ou=OrgUnit',
                                                  [
                                                    'cn=Someone Else,ou=OrgUnit'
                                                  ]
                                                ]
        };
```

Comment: Just for reference, could you post the managers hash too?

Comment: So `manager` is the _parent_ id?

Comment: Yes. Each employee has a `DN` in LDAP, and a `manager` DN (which references the same directory).

Comment: And it's a 1:N relationship?

Comment: Yes. Each person has exactly one 'manager'. (I don't think there are any loops - that would be weird).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need is a *directed graph*, and I suggest using the [`Graph::Directed`](http://metacpan.org/module/Graph::Directed) module, whose methods are documented in [`Graph`](http://metacpan.org/module/Graph)

This program will build the graph for you, but without any data I couldn't test it beyond making sure it compiles

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';
use feature 'say';

use Net::LDAP;
use Graph::Directed;
use Data::Dumper;

my $ldap   = Net::LDAP->new('my_ldap_server');
my $result = $ldap->bind('bind_dn');
die if $result->code;

my $search = $ldap->search(
    base   => 'ou=yaddayadda',
    scope  => 'subtree',
    filter => 'objectClass=person',
    attrs  => ['manager'],
);

my $g = Graph::Directed->new;

for my $found ( $search->entries ) {
    my $mgr = $found->get_value('manager');
    my $dn  = $result->dn;
    $g->add_edge($mgr, $dn);
}

say $g;
```

The resulting `Graph::Directed` object has a stringification overload so you can examine it superficially by simply printing it, but when you want to interrogate the structure further you will need to know some of the terms of [*graph theory*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_%28discrete_mathematics%29). For instance, `$g->source_vertices` will return a list of all nodes that have descendants but no parents—in this case, a list of senior management, or `$g->is_cyclic` will return *true* if your data has any loops anywhere

---

Here's an example of a program that uses your brief sample data to display a hierarchical tree of nodes

```perl
use strict;
use warnings 'all';
use Graph::Directed;

my $data = {
    'cn=Firstname Lastname,ou=OrgUnit' => [
        'cn=Personame Lastname,ou=OrgUnit',
        'cn=AnotherPerson NameHere,ou=OrgUnit',
    ],
    'cn=AnotherPerson NameHere,ou=OrgUnit' =>
        [ 'cn=Someone Else,ou=OrgUnit', ]
};

my $g = Graph::Directed->new;

for my $mgr ( keys %$data ) {
    $g->add_edge($mgr, $_) for @{ $data->{$mgr} };
}

dump_tree($_) for $g->source_vertices;


sub dump_tree {
    my ($node, $level) = ( @_, 0);
    print '   ' x $level, $node, "\n";
    dump_tree($_, $level+1) for $g->successors($node);
}
```

#### output

```
cn=Firstname Lastname,ou=OrgUnit
   cn=AnotherPerson NameHere,ou=OrgUnit
      cn=Someone Else,ou=OrgUnit
   cn=Personame Lastname,ou=OrgUnit
```

Comment: That looks to be what I'm after, but I'm going to have to do a bit more reading to figure it out.

Comment: I'd like to print a tree-style org chart as my starting point. (With a view to extracting JSON -> D3)

Comment: With my data set - I get a lot of results for "source_vertices" and given I'm pretty sure most of my entries have a 'manager' this seems unexpected.

Comment: @Sobrique: You should check your raw data. It may be useful to export it as a list of manager -> worker pairs directly from the LDAP data. The nodes listed by `source_vertices` certainly have no parent/predecessor and you should be able to see why. A chart would probably be best written as a recursive subroutine that starts at any of the nodes in the `source_vertices` list and (recursively) creates a list of workers using `$node->successors`

Comment: @Sobrique: It does sound like it. Unfortunately my knowledge of LDAP is minimal. My example of  a call to `successors` should have been `$g->successors($node)`. I've added to my solution some simple code that dumps your example data as a tree structure

Comment: Found the problem - some genius has decided that 'GB' needs to be lower case in the manager field, but upper case in the dn.

Answer (score 2):

@Hunter McMillen [unfortunately deleted his very good but slightly off answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35749695/1331451). Here is my attempt to augment his code by turning the relationship from *underling -> boss* towards *boss -> underlings*.

To simulate the LDAP responses, I created a simple Moose class.

```
package Person;
use Moose;

has name => ( is => 'ro' );
has boss => ( is => 'ro', predicate => 'has_boss' );

package main;
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Printer;

# make a randomized list of people
my %people = map { $_->name => $_ }
    map { 
      Person->new( 
        name => $_->[0], ( $_->[1] ? ( boss => $_->[1] ) : () ) 
      ) 
    } (
      [qw( ceo )],                       [qw( head_of_dept ceo)],
      [qw( person head_of_dept)],        [qw( person_with_staff head_of_dept )],
      [qw( person3 person_with_staff )], [qw( person4 person_with_staff )],
    );

my %manages;
foreach my $p (values %people) {
    push @{ $manages{ $p->boss } }, $p->name if $p->has_boss;
}

# this part shamelessly stolen from @HunterMcMillen's deleted answer
sub build_tree {
    my ($person) = @_;

    my @subtrees;
    foreach my $managee ( @{ $manages{$person} } ) {
        push @subtrees, build_tree($managee);
    }

    return { $person => \@subtrees };
}

p build_tree 'ceo';
```

Here's the output.

```
\ {
    ceo   [
        [0] {
            head_of_dept   [
                [0] {
                    person   []
                },
                [1] {
                    person_with_staff   [
                        [0] {
                            person4   []
                        },
                        [1] {
                            person3   []
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

This should be more or less what you want.

Comment: @HunterMcMillen I was just commenting how to change the data structure so it would work with your code when you deleted. :P

Comment: oops, I guess I misunderstood. I was pretty sure the algorithm was correct; but got caught up in other things so I couldn't revisit it this morning

Comment: @hunter it's correct, you just assumed the wrong original structure. :)